# LLVM | check if a value is signed

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

How to check if a `llvm::Value` is signed or not (provided that it is either an integer or a float/double)?

My attempt:
From [docs for `Value`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a6393a2d4fe7e10b28a0dcc35f881567b)

```
Type* getType() const;
```

Can return a `Type` object containing the type information of a `Value`.
It is easy to check whether `Value` is integer/float/double using it:

```
bool isFloatTy() const;
bool isDoubleTy() const;
```

But I am having trouble figuring out how to check whether `Type` is a signed number or not, since there is no method like `bool isSignedTy() const;` or anything like it.

How do I do the check?

Comment: Not quite sure if this is still true: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14723945/4181011

Comment: A quick search tells me that LLVM does not distinguish between signed and unsigned integer types. Different IR instructions interpret the data differently (`udiv` vs `sdiv`) but the data has only one type. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519005/how-to-distinguish-signed-and-unsigned-integer-in-llvm and its references...

Comment: Maybe if you include more info about your use case, someone could make a suggestion on how to appropriately handle the issue without adding extra data.